# Using Hadoop to update MySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop

I'm using my reducers to input data into MySQL. 
My concern is that in some cases, multiple reducers are launched for the same key simultaneously. In that case, there is a chance that the DB could be updated twice by the same data. 
Is there a way to protect against that?

Would it make sense to turn off autocommit mode in the SQL connection in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can change setting:

```
mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution
```

That would disable speculative execution of reduce tasks if this is you case.

The other way I would suggest is to use Sqoop to write to MySQL: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal

Answer (score 0):

I think this situation has nothing to done with autocommits. If they are not too much and do not cost a considerable amount of overhead, then ignore them because they won't break up the consistency. All your reducers are doing to execute SQL queries, how can you prevent them to execute queries for the same keys? I think you should solve this issue in your mapreduce function, because this is not a case that DBMS can handle since all it does is to execute given query in the database.

Comment: The problem is essentially caused by 2 reducers running over the same key set...so the only other solution available might be to some not have that happen...but not sure if I can configure hadoop to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...it was turning off speculative execution